# boost::asio asynchronous timer as an interrupt

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio, interrupt

As I understand it, I should be able to use a boost:asio asynchronous timer to trigger a callback every n milliseconds whilst my program is doing something else without needing threads. Is that assumption correct ?

I put together the following test program which just prints the handler messages and never prints the rand() values. What I want is to see all the floating point numbers scroll down the screen, then every 250ms a handler message should appear in amongst them.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::posix_time::time_duration interval(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(250));
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service,interval);

void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error);

void timer_init() {
   timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at()+interval);
   timer.async_wait(handler);
}

void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
   static long count=0;
   std::cout << "in handler " << count++ << std::endl;
   std::cout.flush();
   timer_init();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   timer.async_wait(handler);
   io_service.run();

   std::vector<double> vec;
   for (long i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
      double x=std::rand();
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
      std::cout.flush();
      vec.push_back(x);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
io_service.run();
```

Is a blocking call.  It's true that you can have multiple things happening asynchronously in one thread using ASIO, but you cannot have ASIO running in the same thread as code which is not integrated with ASIO.  This is a classic event-driven model, where all the work gets done in response to some readiness notification (timers, in your case).

Try moving your vector/rand code to a function and passing that function to io_service::post(), which will then run that code within the context of its run() method.  Then when you invoke run(), both things will happen (though not truly concurrently, as that would require threads).

Comment: "you cannot have ASIO running in the same thread as code which is not integrated with ASIO" - this is not exact. One can interleave a main application loop with `poll_one` calls.

Comment: By the way, if he `post`s the whole function, the timer handler wouldn't get called until the function is over.

Answer (score 2):

As John Zwinck mentioned, `io_service::run()` blocks - it's a main `asio` loop that dispatches completion handlers. However, instead of calling `run`, you can "manually" process the `io_service` queue by interleaving `io_service::poll_one` with your loop:

```
for (long i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
      double x=std::rand();
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
      std::cout.flush();
      vec.push_back(x);
      io_service.poll_one();
   }
```